# Why is the date of the answer earlier than the date of the question?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, dates

Found a strange case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses).

[bdonlan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/871508/1249581) was given on **May 16 '09 at 2:08**, while the question itself was asked *a year later* on **Apr 19 '10 at 18:00**.

How did it happen?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Merged or not, but it looks damn weird `:)`

Comment: +1 for eagle eye VisioN...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is the result of a merge operation.

bdonlan's answer originally appeared under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871505/why-have-while1-in-xmlhttprequest-response) (posted May 16 '09 at 2:05), which was then merged into the newer one.

Comment: How did you know that? In the earlier question there is a link, but in the later question there is no.

Comment: @VisioN - See the [revision of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/871508/revisions)

Comment: OK, yeah. That was the place I accidentally haven't checked. Thanks!